# Google Charts, place labels between major gridlines

Tags: google-visualization

I have a `ComboChart` with a 'line' series for an end of month statistic, and 'bars' for a daily statistic.

I used the `ticks` option to place major gridlines at the end of each month, instead of the beginning.

Similar to the below chart, the labels are centered directly below the 'month end' major gridlines.

I've been asked to move the labels to the left, between two major gridlines instead of centered on the end of one.

[image]

I don't see any such option, and am looking for a solution or workaround.

I considered changing major lines to 'mid-month', making the lines invisible, and adding minor gridlines which would then land at month end. Unfortunately, it is not so easy on a monthly chart with daily detail, because different months have different number of days and thus variable distance between major gridlines.

I'm thinking there might be a way to shift the labels to the left with relative positioning? What would you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Got it! You can actually have the text anchored on the right instead of center, causing the text to appear to the left of the corresponding major gridline.

```
var options = {
  //.......
  hAxis: {
    slantedText: true, // anchors text as desired, rotates the text counter-clockwise
    slantedTextAngle: .00001, // disables rotation (setting this to zero caused labels to disappear entirely)
    showTextEvery: 1, // needed when slantedTextAngle is set to a small value
  }
}
// pass the options as you normally would when calling chart.draw
```